# Javascript based drop-down list takes too long to show up

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a Javascript and PHP backed coding which takes values from a table in Mysql database and display them on front-end to user. The values are cities which show up when user selects his Country and Province/State. For e.g if user selects US as country and Florida as Province/State than all cities of Florida show up in a drop-down list.

Now the problem is that this cities drop-down list takes TOO LONG to show after a user has selected his Country and State/Province like it takes about 15 seconds which is too long for user to weight.How to fix this?

If i delete extra cities from MYSQL Database will it effect the performance?Like at the present i have about 1000 extra cities in my database which are of no use. If i delete them all will that make my drop-down list fast?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter, you are probably doing something wrong. Mysql is pretty fast and these 1000 cities do not matter. It could be the reason on the UI end, the way you are handling it.

This is how it would be:

I assume you have `cities` table with `country_id` or `state_id` in it, based on the selection of the country, have an ajax call and call a function that would execute a query like:

```
select * from cities where state_id= //your state_id from via ajax call
```

fill the result set in the city drop down

Comment: Ok but  i am not too good at Ajax.What if i make indexes to my columns in database.will that work?

Comment: ajax is very simple..if you learn it today, you will be in advantage from now onwards... it is very easy..try out